# Which framework can I use to create a website?

Tags: html, framework, mobile

I want to create a website like a technology related blog. And also want to expand it to many other topics in the future. 
Which framework will be the best and the easiest to implement? I also want dynamic contents to be displayed as well as html5 format webpage.
The webpage should also be compatible with mobile devices. 
Kindly mention the link along with the name of the framework. 
If any additional tools are required, please mention it as well.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to software recommendations! Are you looking for a free,  or paid framework. If paid,  what's your budget?

Comment: Most preferably free. If a paid framework gives some features that are extraordinary which is not provided in any free, then I would go for paid. Can you tell me some framework which is free as well as provides excellent features and is easy to use?

Comment: You're asking for free advice, and what better suggestions with better options. Then you need to give better information as to what you want. We're not mind readers, and need to no more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com)?

> Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JS framework for developing responsive, mobile first projects on the web.

**Features:**

- Great for making responsive webpages
- Free
- Mobile friendly
- Highly flexible/customizable
- Easy to learn/use

You can view or download examples and free templates at [startbootstrap.com](http://startbootstrap.com)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that out. Would also like to check out more easier options.

Comment: Checked out bootstrap and the templates you mentioned. Looks really cool! Are there other frameworks which are better?

Comment: @user5349774 I don't really know much other frameworks for Web development,  as I only made a couple websites before,  and never used anything other than Bootstrap. I'm sure there's simpler things out there, but keep in mind,  simpler generally means less flexible/less features. Bootstrap isn't really that hard to learn,  either. It may look intimidating at first,  but after an hour or two of reading/watching tutorials online,  it's pretty easy to get the hang of.